# knockout apply binding to generated binding inside html binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am generating the following in a for loop (ignore the jade template syntax for now):

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs(data-bind="foreach: channels", id="galery_tabs")
  li
    a(data-toggle='tab', data-bind="attr: {href: '#tab_section_' + __kb.object.cid},html: name() + ' <i class=\"icon-remove close\" data-binding=\"click: removeChannel\"></i>'")
```

When I call .applyBindings it will correctly render my A element with the Icon that has a binding inside.

Question: How do I make  second pass apply to ensure the dynamically generated binding is now applied to all Icon elements as well?

Comment: man, we can't ignore that jade template syntax.. please, put a good HTML code

Comment: Why are you using the `html` binding here? Why don't you just put the `<i> `inside your `<a>`?

Comment: Im using html binding because i dynamically merge content the Name of that "tab" plus the "x" icon that needs to remove the tab. if I put the icon outside of the a it screws up the tab content. maybe i should solve it that way lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `html` binding for the scenario.

You can just put your `<i>` inside the `<a>` and you can use the KO container-less syntax to add the `name` property before the icon:

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs(data-bind="foreach: channels", id="galery_tabs")
  li
    a(data-toggle='tab', data-bind="attr: {href: '#tab_section_' + __kb.object.cid}")
      // ko text: name 
      // /ko
      i.icon-remove.close(data-binding="click: removeChannel")
```

And the generated HTML will look like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: channels" id="galery_tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: {href: '#tab_section_' + __kb.object.cid}">
      <!-- ko text: name -->
      <!-- /ko--><i data-binding="click: removeChannel" class="icon-remove close"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Whaoaaa.. buddy you're my hero. Solution worked like charm. \m/. kudos! Never considered containerless bindings.. awesome!